# RPC integrity privilege in processs

Tags: windows, security, api, debugging, winapi

I have 2 processes running in my system (Windows 7 )one of them is with medium integrity level and the second is with a low integrity level.

if my medium integrity send an RPC call to the low integrity process does the code get execute in a low or medium integrity level ?

Answer (score 0):

The code will run in the integrity of the process that invokes it. Thus, in your case, the code will get executed with the integrity of the RPC Server.